# Javascript audio play on click and stop on click

Tags: javascript, html, audio

Current code:

```html
<script>
  function play() {
    var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
    audio.play();
  }
</script>

<button class="matrixBtn" value="PLAY" onclick="play()">star shopping</button>
<audio id="audio" src="xxx"></audio>
```

When I press the button the music starts, which is exactly what I want. But I also want if I press the button again that the music stops. How can I do this without create a second button?

Answer (score 0):

the `<audio>` tag is a [`HTMLMediaElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement), so it has a property [`.paused`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/paused) which you can use to determine the current state and act accordingly:

```
function playPause() {
  var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
  if(audio.paused)audio.play();
  else audio.pause();
}
```